# display "result not found" if no result in database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display a message "result not found" if user search something that do not exits in database.
here is my code but it didnt works.

can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
 <?php
        include 'database_conn.php';

        $eventCat = $_GET['catID'];
        $eventVenue =$_GET['venueName1'];

        $sqlSearch = " SELECT * FROM te_events 

                     WHERE catID = '$eventCat' AND venueID = '$eventVenue'";


        $rsSearch = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSearch) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <thead>
        <th>Title</th> 
        </thead>
    <?php
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsSearch)){
            //extract each field$
            $id         = $row  ["eventID"];
            $title      = $row  ["eventTitle"];
            $desc       = $row  ["eventDescription"];
            $venueId    = $row  ["venueID"];
            // $venue       = $row  ["venueName"];
            // $location   = $row  ["location"];
            $categoryId = $row  ["catID"];
            //$category   = $row  ["catDesc"];
            $eStart     = $row  ["eventStartDate"];
            $eEnd       = $row  ["eventEndDate"];
            $ePrice     = $row  ["eventPrice"]; 


        if(!empty($row)){

       //start a row
            echo"<tr>\n";
            //output the url
            echo"<td>\n";
            echo"<div><a href =\"allDetails.php?eventID=$id\">
                 $title</a></div>\n";
            echo"</td>\n";
        }
            else{
                echo "No event found! Please select other option.\n";



        }

        }
        mysqli_free_result($rsSearch);
        mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `if(num_rows >0){ while...{...} } else{ // not found }` being pseudo here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- u mean put if(num_row>0) infront of the while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsSearch)) ?

Comment: @ChiShen yes. You need to check for no. of rows returned before iterating through the result set.

Comment: yes, what I wrote was pseudo code. See the manual on that http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php  and its usage.

Comment: well someone posted an answer, just accept that. I'm not in this for rep

Comment: thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the amount of rows and then write your code based on the result.

```
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($rsSearch); 

if($rows > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsSearch)){

// code for results

} 

} else {

// legend for no results

}
```

Edit: you don't need to ask the mysql result array whether the line is populated or empty, the line itself will never be empty, it will simply not exist in the array if the query didn't find any data.